# Why Filter get data before prime := <- ch

Tags: go

https://play.golang.org/p/AyKy5odhfZw

In my sight, prime := <- ch this line is before `go Filter ()` , every time data put into ch will be got out by prime directly.

```
// A concurrent prime sieve
package main

import "fmt"

// Send the sequence 2, 3, 4, ... to channel 'ch'.
func Generate(ch chan<- int) {
    for i := 2; ; i++ {
        ch <- i // Send 'i' to channel 'ch'.
    }
}

// Copy the values from channel 'in' to channel 'out',
// removing those divisible by 'prime'.
func Filter(in <-chan int, out chan<- int, prime int) {
    for {
        i := <-in // Receive value from 'in'.
        if i%prime != 0 {
            out <- i // Send 'i' to 'out'.
        }
    }
}

// The prime sieve: Daisy-chain Filter processes.
func main() {
    ch := make(chan int) // Create a new channel.
    go Generate(ch)      // Launch Generate goroutine.
    for i := 0; i < 10; i++ {
        prime := <-ch
        fmt.Println(prime)
        ch1 := make(chan int)
        go Filter(ch, ch1, prime)
        ch = ch1
    }
}
```

Comment: Put your code in the question.

Answer (score 1):

Filter does not receive data first.

The way the code is written means that the variable prime will always receive the **first** value on the output of the filter goroutine created in the previous loop (or the generator on the first loop).

The next time around the main loop the channel variable `ch` will have changed to output of the next filter due to the line `ch=ch1` at the end of the loop. All further integers beyond the first output by a filter will pass to the next filter in the chain.

Placing a few print statements in the filter goroutine will let you see what is happening:

```
   func Filter(in <-chan int, out chan<- int, prime int) {
    for {
        i := <-in // Receive value from 'in'.

        if i%prime != 0 {
            fmt.Printf("Prime filter (%d): passing %d\n", prime, i)
            out <- i // Send 'i' to 'out'.
        } else {
            fmt.Printf("Prime filter (%d): filtered %d\n", prime, i)
        }
    }
}
```

It's a little messy that the goroutines in the pipeline aren't shut down elgantly by closing the generator but that's another story :)